# UITableView reload data flashes for a second

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, reloaddata

I am using pagination on UITableView, after the first load when the next items is about to come or as I reload the tableView it flashes for a second and then comes to it's last position. But it does not happen every time having a hard time solving this out. Anyone can help me please?

Here is the code I am using to reload the data in the tableView

```
func handleWSSuccessResponse(_ arrRestaurant:[Restaurant],filterBy:filteringByValues){
    let offSet = self.IBtblUserFeed.contentOffset
    print(arrRestaurant.count)
    if (self.arrRestaurants.count > 0) {
        if arrRestaurant.count > 0 && arrRestaurant.count <= 10 {
            if arrRestaurant.count % 10 != 0 {
                isDataLoading = false

                actInd.stopAnimating()
            }
            if !(self.isFromRefresh) {
                self.arrRestaurants = self.arrRestaurants + arrRestaurant
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if (self.isFromRefresh) {
                    self.IBtblUserFeed.reloadData()
                } else {
                    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
                    self.IBtblUserFeed.reloadData()
                    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
                    self.IBtblUserFeed.layoutIfNeeded()
                    self.IBtblUserFeed.setContentOffset(offSet, animated: false)
                }
            }
        } else {
            isDataLoading = false

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if (self.isFromRefresh) {
                    self.IBtblUserFeed.reloadData()
                } else {
                    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
                    self.IBtblUserFeed.reloadData()
                    self.IBtblUserFeed.layoutIfNeeded()
                    self.IBtblUserFeed.setContentOffset(offSet, animated: false)
                    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        self.arrRestaurants = arrRestaurant

        if arrRestaurant.count % 10 != 0 {
            isDataLoading = false
            actInd.stopAnimating()
        }

        if self.arrRestaurants.count == 0 {
            self.IBtblUserFeed.tableHeaderView = nil
            self.IBtblUserFeed.tableHeaderView?.isHidden = true
        } else {
            if filterBy.isFiltering{
            } else {
                self.IBtblUserFeed.tableHeaderView = self.header()
            }

            self.IBtblUserFeed.tableHeaderView?.isHidden = false
        }

        if filterBy.isFiltering{
            self.reloadTableView()
            // tejas changes
            // filterRestaurant(filterBy: filterBy)
        }else{
            self.reloadTableView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it is due to modifying the content offset of the table view.

Comment: If I don't modify the contentOffset then reload data starts from top, which I don't want

Comment: I want it just like instagram, as the next data loads, there should be no flick

Answer (score 0):

Your example code is too cluttered with unrelated things to give a solid answer; however, I think that the problem is related to the use of `reloadData`; you should instead use `insertRows(at:with:)` to get smoothly appended rows.

So whenever you append restaurant model objects to your array (from the code it looks like you never apply other changes like modifications or removals), generate the index paths of the new rows ...

```
let indexPaths = (countBeforeAdding..<countAfterAdding).map { IndexPath.init(row: $0, section: 0) }
```

... and insert them into the table view:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: Even after trying this method my tableview scroll to top, which I don't want it should stay at the point where I was calling the api to fetch the next values.

Comment: That's why I used tableview.setcontentoffset

Comment: But since after reloading the tableview or by trying your method, it scrolls to top and I am making it to scroll at the last offset without animation. This causes flicker to happen.

Comment: @AtplMohali are you still using `reloadTable` somewhere?

Comment: No, this is the only place where I am reloading the data.

Comment: It does not flicker at all the loading points, but does flicker at some points.

Comment: Should I use collectionView instead of tableView

Comment: You should diagnose the problem by creating a minimal version of view from scratch -- just a table view with dummy data which appends batches of rows when a navbar button is pressed (you can even do that in a Playground)... without all the `setContentOffset`, `layoutIfNeeded`etc. -- those should not be necessary for a simple table like this.
And: a table view should be perfectly capable of doing what you want -- a collection view will not make things simpler, especially if you are already struggling with a table view.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this